# How to manage application.properties in a utility project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, application.properties

I'm working on a project intended for managing images (it creates a table in the database with references to the image files so I don't need to upload them directly to the database). I'm trying to create this project as a JAR that I can import in any other project.

So far, I can create the JAR file, but when I import this JAR file in another project so I can use its features, it seems like the imported JAR will not use the destination project's application.properties. It will use its own.

The only important thing in the application.properties to be set (to get it to work) is the jdbc driver and the database url and credentials, but it should be using the info contained in the destination project application.properties file.

And if I delete or rename the utility project application.properties I won't be able to generate the JAR.

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Is this an option for you - Let the user of your jar set the properties by exposing a setter ? And the application using the jar can initialise it for you.

Comment: I don't know, to be honest, but I'm going to investigate about it. Thank you! (I edited my original question to say that the only important info contained in the application.properties is regarding jdbc driver, database url, username and password. But it shouldn't use its own. It should use the destination project jdbc driver, url, puser and pass)

Comment: I don't know, how  you start your application, but in general there are a lot of ways to externalize your configuration. E.g. you could add a custom aplication.properties on start witth cli params: ``` --spring.config.location```. There are many other ways, for further info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: You should expose the JDBC Connection Class via a class, an interface or an abstract class. Then, when you import this Jar in another project, that project class can override the functions to set the values.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to fix my issue. I've been about to delete the question, but I thought it could be useful for someone else in the future, so I decide to add an answer:

(I'll explain for people without much experience, like me)

And a "Tool project": which will produce a JAR
I have a "Main project": which will import the JAR to take advantage of the Tool Project features.

In order to create a tool (or a utility project. I think it's the same thing), I created a Spring Boot project, as I usually would do.

That tool project doesn't need to have controllers. Instead, it has Services with public methods, which Main Project will use. Also, if needed (as in my particular case), it has Entities and Repositories.

In the Tool Project's POM.xml file, place the least amount of dependencies possible. Don't place any dependencies like `MySQL`, `JPA`, etc... since the Main Project will have them as well. Also, remove the `<parent>` tag and its content.

You can also delete de Application class (The starter class) or just comment the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

In the application.properties (or YML), you don't really need to have anything.

After that, unless I forgot something, you're ready to go:

1. Clean
2. Maven Update
3. Install

After you install, a new folder will be created inside:

`C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.m2\repository\com\guillermo\myTool\MyTool\1.0.0`

Now, go to your Main Project and add the dependency for the tool.

Mine is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.guillermo.myTool</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyTool</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I really hope this helps someone!